# ActionController::Routing Error (Nested Resources - Rails 4 Ruby 2)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, nested-routes

I am attempting to nest resources in such away that i can avoid nesting a resource 3 deep.

**my original plan was to do something like:** (just so you can see my thought process)

```
  resources :properties do
    resources :stalls do 
      resources :bookings 
    end
  end
end
```

**What I have ended up doing is this:**

```
  ## Nested Relationship for Proerty / Stall ##
  resources :properties do
    resources :stalls, except: [:index], controller: 'properties/stalls'
  end
  ## END Nested Relationship for Property / Stall ##

  ## Nested Relationship for Stall / Bookiing ##
  resources :stalls do
    resources :bookings, except: [:index], controller: 'stalls/bookings'
  end
  ## END Nested Relationship for Stall / Bookiing ##
```

Every thing is working up to the point where I submit the Bookings form.. and even at that it dose commit the booking and creats the record, but dosnt redirect back to stalls/1.

**the server error is:**

```
Started POST "/stalls/1/bookings" for ::1 at 2015-12-13 23:12:39 -0700
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by Stalls::BookingsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xsGxr2PLf7vHuXL6xgjBHyTl2Ub8mD07S7iJXM7vNodjH32DXgdUELFk6pJSUxZhkp+sZS31g4E4kY9AVnDyoQ==", "booking"=>{"stall_id"=>"", "visitor_id"=>"", "arrival_date(1i)"=>"2015", "arrival_date(2i)"=>"12", "arrival_date(3i)"=>"14", "arrival_time(1i)"=>"2015", "arrival_time(2i)"=>"12", "arrival_time(3i)"=>"14", "arrival_time(4i)"=>"06", "arrival_time(5i)"=>"08", "departure_date(1i)"=>"2015", "departure_date(2i)"=>"12", "departure_date(3i)"=>"14"}, "commit"=>"Create Booking", "stall_id"=>"1"}
  Stall Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "stalls".* FROM "stalls" WHERE "stalls"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "bookings" ("arrival_date", "arrival_time", "departure_date", "stall_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["arrival_date", "2015-12-14"], ["arrival_time", "2015-12-14 06:08:00.000000"], ["departure_date", "2015-12-14"], ["stall_id", 1], ["created_at", "2015-12-14 06:12:40.035416"], ["updated_at", "2015-12-14 06:12:40.035416"]]
   (6.0ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/stalls/1
Completed 302 Found in 53ms (ActiveRecord: 10.4ms)


Started GET "/stalls/1" for ::1 at 2015-12-13 23:12:40 -0700

ActionController::RoutingError - uninitialized constant StallsController:
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:65:in `rescue in controller'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:60:in `controller'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:41:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:821:in `call'
  warden (1.2.4) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.4) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:84:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  web-console (2.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:39:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  quiet_assets (1.1.0) lib/quiet_assets.rb:27:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
  /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
```

**My Stalls Controller is as such:**

```
class Properties::StallsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_stall, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /stalls
  # GET /stalls.json
  def index
    @stalls = Stall.all
  end

  # GET /stalls/1
  # GET /stalls/1.json
  def show
    @stall = Stall.find(params[:id])
    ## Nested Bookings ##
    @bookings = @stall.bookings
  end

  # GET /stalls/new
  def new
    @property = Property.find(params[:property_id])
    @stall = Stall.new
  end

  # GET /stalls/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /stalls
  # POST /stalls.json
  def create
    @property = Property.find(params[:property_id])
    @stall = Stall.new(stall_params)
    @stall.property = @property

    respond_to do |format|
      if @stall.save
        format.html { redirect_to @property, notice: 'Stall was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @property }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @property.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /stalls/1
  # PATCH/PUT /stalls/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @stall.update(stall_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @stall, notice: 'Stall was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @stall }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @stall.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /stalls/1
  # DELETE /stalls/1.json
  def destroy
    @stall.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to stalls_url, notice: 'Stall was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_stall
      @stall = Stall.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def stall_params
      params.require(:stall).permit(:property_id, :stall_type, :location, :status)
    end
end
```

I think my problem is that the controller has been refactored to have a relationship with properties, I have tried to create a new stalls controller but this didn't work either.

**Just for reference my bookings controller is:**

```
class Stalls::BookingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_booking, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /bookings
  # GET /bookings.json
  def index
    @bookings = Booking.all
  end

  # GET /bookings/1
  # GET /bookings/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /bookings/new
  def new
    @stall = Stall.find(params[:stall_id])
    @booking = Booking.new
  end

  # GET /bookings/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /bookings
  # POST /bookings.json
  def create
    @stall = Stall.find(params[:stall_id])
    @booking = Booking.new(booking_params)
    @booking.stall = @stall
    respond_to do |format|
      if @booking.save
        format.html { redirect_to @stall, notice: 'Booking was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @stall }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @stall.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /bookings/1
  # PATCH/PUT /bookings/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @booking.update(booking_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @booking, notice: 'Booking was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @booking }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @booking.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /bookings/1
  # DELETE /bookings/1.json
  def destroy
    @booking.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to bookings_url, notice: 'Booking was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_booking
      @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def booking_params
      params.require(:booking).permit(:visitor_id, :stall_id, :arrival_date, :arrival_time, :departure_date)
    end
end
```

**File Tree Image:**
[image]

Error Screen Error (better_errors gem used)
[image]

Any assistance here would be great, I've exhausted all of my resources, have read the ruby guide, just not sure where I'm going wrong here.

Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Thanks in advance.

> **EDIT #1:**

Displays Suggested Changes:
[image]

Displays new Error Message:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using:

```
  ## Nested Relationship for Stall / Bookiing ##
  resources :stalls do
    resources :bookings, except: [:index], controller: 'stalls/bookings'
  end
```

and then when you do:

```
redirect_to @stall
```

It looks for a controller called `StallsController`, but you don't have such a controller, you have `Properties::StallsController`.

So try editing your route to look like this:

```
   resources :stalls, controller: 'properties/stalls' do
     resources :bookings, except: [:index], controller: 'stalls/bookings'
   end
```

Comment: that just did it! wow something so small.. thanks for you assistance!

Comment: this just taught me something new, really appreciate that ive been stuck on this for days..

Answer (score 1):

You seem to need the use of namespace in your routes

eg:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :articles, :comments
end
```

[check this in the guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing)

Comment: Ok ill give it a try so if i have multiple namespaces would i just copy out the controller into the other namespaces? and then would i change the controller class to admin::properties?

Comment: disregard the refactoring question i was blin when reading the routing documentation.

Comment: I get the same eror using the namespaces??

Comment: I see. It seems that your problem is this part
`redirect_to @stall, notice: 'Booking was successfully created.'`

It would look for the StallsController given the Stall class.. You should explicitly put the path of the @stall, eg: `properties_stall_path(@stall)`

Comment: were getting there.. lol.. it changed the error so im gonna take that as a step in the right direction here.. see edit please

Comment: Cool. Do a `rake routes`  to check the right helper name for the properties_stall_path and replace with the right one

Comment: Thanks for all your help with this! the answer above solved the problem!